# Check if name string contains first and last name

Tags: c#, string, split

I have a string that contains a first and last name and I wanted to split into two separate strings so I used this code:

```
string Delname = bkDel.ContactName;
string[] Deltmp = Delname.Split(' ');
string DelFirstName = Deltmp[0];
string DelLastName = Deltmp[1];
```

It works fine if there is a first and last name but this causes an error if the name string only contains a first name:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

since `Deltmp[1]` is null.

Is there a way to check the name string so if it only contains one string then don't try and split?

Comment: "Is there a way to check the name string so if it only contains one string then don't try and split?" -- Just check the results of the split instead of trying to figure out if you should split or not. Check the length of the array returned by `Split`: `if (Deltmp.Length < 2)`, or `if (Deltmp.Length == 1)`, then only access the `[0]` element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either check on the length of the array:

```
if (Deltmp.Length > 1)
    //Assign to vars
```

Or you can check if the input string contains spaces:

```
if (Delname.Contains(" "))
    //Do split
```

For example:

```
string[] Deltmp = Delname.Split(' ');
if (Deltmp.Length > 1)
    //Assign to both
else
    //Assign to only one
```

Comment: @Quantic `string.Split` does not ignore leading or trailing spaces.  You'll end up with empty strings unless you use an override that takes a `StringSplitOptions` and pass `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`

Comment: @juharr Oops you're right, my bad. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a simple check like this.

```
if(Delname.Split(' ').Count() > 1)
{
    // Has First and Last Name
}
else
{
    // Has Single Name
}
```

Comment: Please don't add salutations/signatures at the end of your post.

Comment: Please do not include your website as a signature.

Comment: Oops, removing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Delname.Trim(' ')` method to delete spaces from start and end, and then check string with `Delname.Contains(" "))`

Answer (score 0):

What about checking the input with regular expressions?  Here is a simple regex pattern, but you may need to get more sophisticated depending on your supported language requirements.

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"[A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+");


string Delname = bkDel.ContactName;
    Delname = Delname.Trim()
    if (!reg.IsMatch(Delname)){
    // Don't split
    return;

}
string[] Deltmp = Delname.Split(' ');
string DelFirstName = Deltmp[0];
string DelLastName = Deltmp[1];
```